# Solving polynomial equation using Fermat little theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am a bit confused on notation. I can't find a reference in notation in my textbook as to what this means. Here it goes:

Let p = 13. Compute $\phi$$_{11}$$(3x^{233} + 4x^6 + 2x^{37} + 3)$

This isn't a proof problem or anything, but it it asking me to evaluate the x at 11?

Edit:

Sorry guys, this question has been blurry at best and I'm sorry for the little amount of info.

The function is the evaluation homomorphism and it's domain is:

$\phi_{11}: Z_{p}[x] -> Z_{p}$

Even so, I really don't know how to approach this. Freligh doesn't offer problems on computation like this. I see a hint on Fermats theorem in the problem, but I don't see how it helps.

Comment: I don't understand where $p = 13$ might be used; did you write the whole problem statement? Anyway... usually $\phi_n$ denotes the $n$-th [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: So it's not possible that it could be the evaluation homomorphism?

Comment: Many things are possible because you didn't provide enough context... this could be clearer if you told us where you found this problem.

Comment: It is possible that this means to calculate the value of the polynomial for $x=11$ modulo $13$. But it is really not clear either. Can you give more context?

Comment: Yeah quid, I think that is it. I didn't see a little note at the top specifying where the homomorphism. It is the evaluation homomorphism

Comment: I just updated my question guys. Sorry for the confusion n stuff

Comment: Well, $233 \equiv 5 \pmod{12}$, hence $11^{233} \equiv 11^5 \pmod{13}$. Similarly, $37 \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$, so $11^{37} \equiv 11 \pmod{13}$. Right now I don't see how you could avoid computing $11^5$ and $11^6$ modulo $13$, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $233 \equiv 5 \pmod{12}$, hence by Fermat's little theorem $11^{233} \equiv 11^5 \pmod{13}$. Similarly, $37 \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$ implies $11^{37} \equiv 11 \pmod{13}$. Thus you are left to evaluate
$$
\begin{align}
3 \cdot 11^5 + 4 \cdot 11^6 + 2 \cdot 11 + 3 &\equiv (3 - 4 \cdot 2) (-2)^5 - 1 \\
&\equiv 5 \cdot 2^5 - 1 \\
&\equiv 10 \cdot 2^4 - 1 \\
&\equiv -3 \cdot 2^4 - 1 \\
&\equiv -12 \cdot 2^2 - 1 \\
&\equiv 4 - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}
\end{align}
$$
Observe that here I've liberally switched between the systems of representatives $\{0,1,\dotsc,12\}$ and $\{-6,-5,\dotsc,6\}$ whenever it eased my computations.

Comment: So I can play with the exponents in mod as well? This is the same in any circumstance?

Comment: And also, that conversion when you went from {0,1,...,12} to {-6,-5,...,6}. How come you are allowed to do that?

Comment: Take any non-zero $a \in \Bbb{Z}_{13}$ and consider, for example, $233 = 5 + k12$. Then $a^{233} = a^{5 + k12} = a^5 \cdot (a^{12} )^k\equiv_{13} a^5 \cdot 1^k = a^5$, where the equalities are due to the properties of powers, while the $\equiv$ is due to Fermat's little theorem. You can do this whenever you are *evaluating* a polynomial, but you can't say that $x^{233} \equiv x^5$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{13}[x]$, because $x$ is not an element of $\Bbb{Z}_{13}$.

Comment: You are always allowed to choose the representative of a class that better suits your purposes. This is because $\Bbb{Z}_n$ is [*defined*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) as $\Bbb{Z}/\sim$ where $x \sim y$ if and only if $n \mid (x-y)$. In other words, $\Bbb{Z}_n = \{[x]_n : x \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ where $[x]_n = \{ y \in \Bbb{Z} : x \sim y \}$ (this is why they are called residue *classes*). The "magic" is that $[x \cdot y]_n = [x]_n \cdot [y]_n$ and $[x+y]_n = [x]_n + [y]_n$, so you can work with representatives (assuming the sets) instead of the sets themselves.